# jQuery code to simplify

Tags: jquery, simplify

I've got this code but it's a bit repeating itself, is there a way to make it shorter?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allTabs = jQuery('#front, #blog, #portfolio, #pages, #colors, #fonts');
    allTabs.hide();

    jQuery('#front-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#front').show();
    });

    jQuery('#blog-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#blog').show();
    });

    jQuery('#portfolio-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#portfolio').show();
    });

    jQuery('#pages-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#pages').show();
    });

    jQuery('#colors-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#colors').show();
    });

    jQuery('#fonts-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery('#fonts').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code so we can see the relationship between elements (i.e. #front and #front-show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allTabs.click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    allTabs.hide();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var el = jQuery('#'+id.substring(0,id.indexOf('-')));
    el.show();
});
```

Comment: He wants to bind to the click event for the -show variants, not the entries in allTabs.

Comment: Why was this accepted? It doesn't duplicate the original functionality in your code. It binds to the regular form of the id (`#blog, #photos, etc`) instead of the -show option, and then it hides all of the tabs and shows itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can utilize [jQuery's multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#fonts-show,#pages-show,#portfolio-show,#blog-show,etc...").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    allTabs.hide();
    $("#"+$(this).attr("id").split("-")[0]).show();
});
```

EDIT: Did not notice the different id between the selectors. Edited the show statement to correct for this.

Comment: What exactly $(this).show(); does? Each link in my case shows differently named div...

Comment: Close, but `$(this).show()` needs to be substituted since it will apply to the wrong id (for example, clicking on `#fonts-show` should cause `$('#fonts').show()` not `$('#fonts-show').show()`)

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Edited the answer, I hope this is proper etiquette on SO.

Comment: Inside the callback, `this` is an element, not a jQuery object, so you can't use `this.attr`, you'll need to either use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: One last note, this approach means that he has to duplicate his list of elements, and he can never use an id with a hyphen in it.

Answer (score 2):

Give them a common class that you can use to select them, then utilize the first part of the ID to build a selector for the `.show()`.

```
jQuery('.someClass').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    allTabs.hide();
    jQuery('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] ).show();  // 'front-show' becomes '#front'
});
```

---

**Update:**

Assuming the one being shown is one of the `allTabs`, I'd do this instead.

```
jQuery('.someClass').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    allTabs.hide().filter('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] ).show();
});
```

Avoids repeated DOM selection.

Also, instead of this:

```
'#' + this.id.split('-')[0]
```

...you could do this:

```
'#' + this.id.replace('-show','')
```

Comment: Or, use this id generation along with the multiple selector by @RockyMadden

Comment: They don't need a common class. They are already collected in allTabs

Comment: @js1568: The ones getting the `show/hide` is a different set than those getting the `click`.

Comment: @Phrogz: Could do that too. I prefer the shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like all of the ids match the same pattern, and you want to bind to the `click` event for each element in `allTabs` (plus -show on the end), you could iterate over your allTabs variable and bind that way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allTabs = jQuery('#front, #blog, #portfolio, #pages, #colors, #fonts');
    allTabs.hide();

    allTabs.each(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var $target = jQuery(this);
        jQuery("#" + id + "-show").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            allTabs.hide();
            $target.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're duplicating the closure. Since you're using `jQuery.each()`, you'll "close around" `i` and `ele` when you assign the handler.

Comment: @patrick: Ah, good point. Updated my answer to remove the inner closure.

Comment: If you don't mind me making a couple other points, it won't work to do `ele.attr('id')` since `ele` will be a DOM element. And you're missing the `event` object in the formal parameters list of the handler, but everyone else is too, except for one guy. ;o)

Comment: The reason I didn't do `$(ele)` in the body of the callback is because we are using the generic collection iterator `jQuery.each`, which, as I understand, will return the value at each point in the collection, which I suppose I wrongly assumed would be a jQuery object instead of just an element.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var allTabs = jQuery('#front, #blog, #portfolio, #pages, #colors, #fonts');
allTabs.hide();

var ids = ['#front', '#blog', '#portfolio', '#pages', '#colors', '#fonts'];
for(var x in ids)
{
    jQuery(ids[x] + '-show').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        allTabs.hide();
        jQuery(ids[x]).show();
    });
}
```

});

Comment: This won't work, since the value of `x` will be the last value of `x` for all of the callback handlers. You need to use a closure to do this properly, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fonts-show,#pages-show,#portfolio-show,#blog-show,etc...').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    allTabs.hide();
    var showId = $(this).attr('id');
    var targetId = id.substring(0,id.indexOf('-'));
    $('#'+targetId).show();
});
```